# How to test flutter interactive viewer widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, size, scale

I'm building an app image, but I'm confused to test interactiveviewer widget ,
I don't have a phone
i only have pc
I tried moving the touchpad but the scale only goes to number 1 and doesn't change
how to test flutter interactive viewer widget?

Comment: have you tried using command key on mac or control on windows to achieve panning?

Comment: i have tried that ctrl + shift + + but it doesn't work